# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required (python)

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am new to python and I'm trying to read a text file. 
This is my code:

```python
import csv
csvreader = csv.reader(open('datatypes.txt', 'rb'))
dataTypes = dict(csvreader)
```

And my datatypes.txt file contains:

```
[('string',6), ('varchar',7)]
```

I'm trying to write datatypes in the above file. However, when I try this I get the error as "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required"....  Am I going in the right direction or I have lost completely??
Would appreciate if anyone can shed any light on this for me... thanks

Comment: It literally contains that? Well, that's not CSV...

Answer (score 1):

That file isn't CSV. Try `ast.literal_eval`:

```python
import ast

with open('datatypes.txt', 'r') as f:
    dataTypes = dict(ast.literal_eval(f.read()))
    # dataTypes: {'varchar': 7, 'string': 6}
```